# Prove that $f(z)=|z| (\arg (z))^2$ can be continuous or extended continuously on $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Consider that $\arg(z)\in (-\pi,\pi]$. We know that the function $f(z)=|z| (\arg (z))^2$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$. Also, $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)=0$, so $f$ is extended continuously to $0$. I have a problem to answer what does $f$ on every point $z=x<0$ (I believe that is continuous on these $x$ if I do it with sequences). Any help please? Thanks.

Comment: Look at $f(x e^{\pm \pi i})$ with $x>0$.

Comment: @Gary this give us continuity of $f$ on $(-\infty, 0)$?

Comment: Yes, when you approach $x<0$ from the upper half plane, or the negative ray, the argument tends to $\pi$. The limit of $f(z)$ will be $|x|\pi^2$. When you approach it from the lower half plane the argument tends to $-\pi$ and then $f$ tends to $|x|\pi^2$.

Comment: Ok thanks I visualize it now with sequences. Is the same idea.